# Which axis does Keras Conv1D layer work on?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm writting a model with Keras for time series analysis. The structure of the info I'm sending to the neural network is `(samples, timesteps, features)`

My idea is to have three steps on the design of the network.
A first step with a (or some) Conv1D layers, then another with LSTMs and finally some Dense layers.

For the first layers (Conv1D), how can I select the axis where the convolution will be performed?
I'm trying to do that on the timesteps axis, but I'm not sure if with something like

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(180, 60, padding="same", strides=5, activation="relu"))
```

the timesteps axis will be used, or a different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, it's applied to the axis with the time steps.

```
import tensorflow as tf

timesteps = 7
features = 10

inputs = tf.random.uniform(shape=(100, timesteps, features), maxval=1, dtype=tf.float32)
filters = tf.random.uniform(shape=(3, 1, 1), maxval=1, dtype=tf.float32)

print(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=5, kernel_size=(3,))(inputs).shape)
```

```
(100, 5, 5)
```

The resulting shape is `(n_samples, time_steps - (kernel_size - 1), filters)`